# summer program for college freshman

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

I'm a college freshman and I'm studying mathematics. Do you know any summer programs that would be suitable for a European student? If you have any personal experience, can you tell me about it? Funding is not a problem for me because I've received a grant for that purpose.

I've found an interesting activity:
http://math.jacobs-university.de/summerschool/2015/index.php
do you know anything about it?

Comment: How have you received a grant for a program without actually knowing any programs?

Comment: @Daniel yes, I can choose the course I want to attend